# Eclipse Mars quits on using the option "open declaration"

Tags: eclipse

I face an issue that whenever I use "open declaration" (the option to view the implementation of method/class) option in eclipse it hangs and quits. To get the log I started it from command line and I have got following log.

Log INFO:

A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:

```
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x0000000107bd0a80, pid=3786, tid=0x0000000000006e03
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_92-b14) (build 1.8.0_92-b14)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.92-b14 mixed mode bsd-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# V  [libjvm.dylib+0x3d0a80]
#
# Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# /****/****/***/MacOS/hs_err_pid3786.log
#
# Compiler replay data is saved as:
# /***/eclipse/Eclipse.app/Contents/MacOS/replay_pid3786.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
#
Abort trap: 6
```

Environment details are

Eclipse Mars(Version: Mars Release (4.5.0) Build id: 20150621-1200)
Java and Jre version -  1.8.0_92.
OS details :  OS X El Capitan version : 10.11 (IOS)

Please help in fixing this issue.

Comment: Hi, I come across this link 

https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8154831

It says that we can fix this bug by moving to jdk 1.7 0r moving to jDK 1.8.77

It worked for me